# vlc stream BLACKMAGIC SDI on Windows

Tags: video-streaming, vlc

How Can I stream with VLC and Blackmagic SDI on WIndows, I tryied this code below, but this not show the video just black screen:

dshow:// :dshow-vdev="Decklink Video Capture (2)" :decklink-caching=100 :dshow-caching=1000 :decklink-mode=pal :dshow-chroma=UYVY :dshow-fps=25

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVbyR.png)